# How to set data type automatically connecting .csv files in DBeaver?

Tags: database, csv, import, dbeaver

I tried to import .csv files to my database in DBeaver,
and I found a difference between

1. connecting to a folder containing the .csv files and importing all of them like a full database
2. importing .csv files as tables to a database I've already made.

When I connect to a folder, DBeaver set the datatypes of columns all to 'String'. However, it interprets them accordingly if I import .csv files individually.

So, I'd like to know how to set data type automatically connecting .csv files in DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

The string column type used by default for CSV driver: https://github.com/simoc/csvjdbc/blob/master/docs/doc.md#columntypes

You can try to change "columnTypes" setting in DBeaver-> CSV connection -> Connection Settings -> Driver Properties.

[image: CSV Driver Properties]